# Remove background from legend ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a `geom_tile` plot, and used color around some of the tiles and used a scale to color them, but then i get the scales in the `legend` with a `grey` background as shown in the figure.

[image]

the plotting is here:

```
 pl <-  geom_tile(aes(fill=er,x,y, color=factor(tst)), size=2) + scale_color_manual(values=c("#339900", "black", "#0197fd"), name="p-\nvalue",labels=paste(levels(df.new$pval.d),table(df.new$pval.d)))  + geom_point(data=test,aes(x=x,y=y),shape=4,size=3)+guides(col=guide_legend(nrow = 3,keyheight = 3))
```

I tried to add : `theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = 'white'))` to the end of the plotting and  `theme(legend.key = element_blank())` but both did not work.

how can i remove this grey background from the ticks of the `legend`.

Comment: Please make your example reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to determine the source of your problem as you didn't provide a reproducable example.

I don't have this problem with my own plots. The solution is probably quite simple: Adding `theme_bw()` to your plotting code might do the trick.